# How to sample an exact number of rows (n<N) with the restriction that they're equally spaced (in a day)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sampling

I have a dataset that is filled throughtout each day with 0 to 48 measurements (one every half an hour) for each mac address (sometimes we may not get every measurement for various reasons). Usually, I group by day and take the average of the measurements but, as the number of mac addresses grow, we intend to take less measurements to compose the average. Here's an example of query I do:

```
select fmc.mac_address, 
           inf.node, 
           inf.uf, 
           inf.cidade,
           date_trunc('day', fmc.data) as data,
           avg(inf.qoe) as qoe, 
           avg(inf.qoe_download) as qoe_download,
           avg(inf.qoe_upload) as qoe_upload, 
           avg(inf.qoe_packetloss) as qoe_packetloss,
           avg(inf.qoe_latency) as qoe_latency, 
           avg(inf.qoe_jitter) as qoe_jitter
    
    from fixa_medicoes_claro fmc inner join public.inference_mac inf on fmc.mac_address = inf.mac
    
    where data >= '2020-12-14'
    and mac_address in {}
    
    group by fmc.mac_address, 
             inf.node, 
             inf.uf, 
             inf.cidade,
             date_trunc('day', fmc.data)
```

Now we want to query a smaller number of samples for each grouped data, with a restriction that, whatever the number of measurements per day for a mac_address, I want to query at max "n" of them, with also the restriction that they are equally spaced in time. Ps.: the timestamp only register the day, so we don't know the hour/minute for a specific sample.

Comment: Maybe tablesample could help you: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to get a random sample:

```
select . . .
from (select fmc.*, inf.*, -- the columns you need
             row_number() over (partition by mac_address order by random()) as seqnum
      from fixa_medicoes_claro fmc inner join
           public.inference_mac inf
           on fmc.mac_address = inf.mac    
      where data >= '2020-12-14' and
            mac_address in {}
     ) fi
where seqnum <= 10
group by . . .
```

If you want the rows to be evenly spaced, then a simple method is `ntile()` with `row_number()`:

```
select . . .
from (select fi.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mac_address, tile order by fmc_data) as seqnum
      from (select fmc.*, inf.*, -- the columns you need
                   ntile(10) over (partition by mac_address order by fmc_data) as tile
            from fixa_medicoes_claro fmc inner join
                 public.inference_mac inf
                 on fmc.mac_address = inf.mac    
            where data >= '2020-12-14' and
                  mac_address in {}
           ) fi
     ) fi
where seqnum <= 1
group by . . .
```